# How do you associate a schema with a payload?

Tags: php, publish-subscribe, snowplow

**For context:**
 I am setting up a PubSub Emitter for snowplow. (For other readers PubSub is a simple queue on Google Cloud Platforms that takes in messages which are an array as input).

```
['data' => 'Name', 'attributes' => 'key pair values of whatever data you are sending']
```

The above is irrelevant except that I must create a custom Emitter class in order to achieve this goal since Google Cloud PubSub has some different connectors than the stereotypical http request/sockets/others that snowplow provides.

**Actual problem:**

I want to set a specific schema for each event I am sending. How do you associate the schema to each payload?

The PHP Tracker SyncEmitter (the most standard snowplow provided Emitter) doesn't allow any custom setting for the schema (as shown below)

```
private function getPostRequest($buffer) {
    $data = array("schema" => self::POST_REQ_SCEHMA, "data" => $buffer);
    return $data;
}
```

It is hardcoded in to every event tracked.

So I investigated. And read up on snowplow trackers a bit more. I am still baffled, and I know I can extend the Payload class and force my own schemas as a variable, but why is it not this way already? I am asking because I am assuming the opensource programmer did it right, and I am not understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The Tracker class contains `trackUnstructuredEvent`:

```
/**
 * Tracks an unstructured event with the aforementioned metrics
 *
 * @param array $event_json - The properties of the event. Has two fields:
 *                           - A "data" field containing the event properties and
 *                           - A "schema" field identifying the schema against which the data is validated
 * @param array|null $context - Event Context
 * @param int|null $tstamp - Event Timestamp
 */
public function trackUnstructEvent($event_json, $context = NULL, $tstamp = NULL) {
    $envelope = array("schema" => self::UNSTRUCT_EVENT_SCHEMA, "data" => $event_json);
    $ep = new Payload($tstamp);
    $ep->add("e", "ue");
    $ep->addJson($envelope, $this->encode_base64, "ue_px", "ue_pr");
    $this->track($ep, $context);
}
```

Which accepts the schema as input. Snowplow wants you to use the Tracker's default function and provided the above as a solution to my issue.

But it still has a schema wrapped around the data(that contains the input schema).... More questions from my own answer...